# Qt5 QOpenGL Error on Execute

Tags: qt, qt5, qwidget

I'm developing a application on Qt Creator Comunnity, Qt Version 5.4.2 on Ubuntu Vivid(15.04). At my computer, the program works fine. But when i run the program on a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS the following error occurs:

```
undefined symbol: _ZN13QOpenGLWidgetC1EP7QWidget6QFlagsIN2Qt10WindowTypeEE
```

Did it happen because of the kernel version?

Answer (score 0):

On Vivid [you have Qt 5.4.1](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/libqt5gui5), on Trusty [you have Qt 5.2.1](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libqt5gui5).

You can't run a program compiled with a *later* Qt version on a machine shipping an *earlier* one.